# $npm_config_variable not working in GitHub Actions

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, github-actions

I am trying to run npm run script that contains $npm_config_testCase

`cross-var node ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha ./$npm_config_testCase --reporter mochawesome --reporter-options reportDir=fileDir/report,reportFilename=report --require mochawesome/register`

Where testCase is variable that I previously set it to

`npm config location --project set testCase=tests/qePositions.test.js`

In the GitHub actions I have added extra line just before the npm run script

`npm config location --project get testCase`

and it returns successfully `qePositions.test.js`

However the npm run script fails to get the $npm_config_testCase value and the script returns no tests were found on that path. I have also tested this locally successfully (Windows machine, where as the GitHub pipe is using ubuntu-latest and that's why I am using cross-var package).
Therefore I started doubting in GitHub pipe. What am I missing there?

Here is the main part of my pipeline.

tests:

```
runs-on: ubuntu-latest
name: Test (chunk ${{ matrix.chunk }})
needs: setup`
  strategy:
  matrix:
    node-version: [16.x]
    chunk: ${{ fromJson(needs.setup.outputs['test-chunk-ids']) }}
steps:
  - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
    uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
  - run: npm install
  - name: Download build artifacts
    uses: actions/download-artifact@v2
  - name: Mocha
    run: |
        echo $CHUNKS | jq '.[${{ matrix.chunk }}] | .[] | @text' | xargs npm config --location project set testCase
        npm config --location project get testCase
        npm run mocha
    env:
      CHUNKS: ${{ needs.setup.outputs['test-chunks'] }}
```